# Powershell recursive WMI query

Tags: scripting, powershell, wmi

I'd like to start at the top of a WMI namespace, recurse through all the objects, then recurse through each object's property list, filtering out and returning to console only those properties that have *mem* in their names.

This is what I have so far:

```
gwmi -namespace "root\cimv2" -list |???? |get-Member -MemberType property | Where-Object { $_.name -match 'mem'}
```

Notice the big |???? in the middle there. If I remove that, the the command *seems* to run, but fails to find properties I know should be found. Why? I *think* it is because I get different output from the following two commands:

```
gwmi "Win32_operatingSystem"  |get-Member -MemberType property (73 lines of output)
gwmi -namespace "root\cimv2" -list  |where-object { $_.Name -eq 'Win32_OperatingSystem' } |get-Member -MemberType property (10 lines of output)
```

---

What I want is a one-liner that recursively concatenates this process:

```
gwmi -namespace "root\cimv2" -list
(manual selection of a WMI class from the list of 1000+ which appear) 
gwmi "win32_OperatingSystem" | get-Member -MemberType property | Where-Object { $_.Definition -match 'mem' }
```

Thanks, and if a working answer is given, I *will* accept and upvote it (annoying when people never do that, isn't it?).

Note added 2009/11/14: I haven't awarded the answer yet because no one has yet provided a *one-liner* which solves the problem.

Comment: Why do you need a one-liner? Just take one of the answers that works and make a function out of it. Then just pass in the parameter for namespace & search term. You'll end up with: _Run-MyFunction_ _namespace_ _searchterm_, which is a lot easier to run from the command line than even a one-liner.

Comment: I need to be able to deliver a troubleshooting step over the phone or IM, with a minimum of hassle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will do what you are looking for in one line. the CIMV2 namespace is there by default but if you wanted to select a different one, you can use gwmi -namesapce.

The "trick" is nesting a where-object in side the foreach-object

```
gwmi -list | % {$_.Properties | ? {$_.Name.Contains('Memory')}} | select Origin,Name
```

Comment: Oh, man. This is *precisely* the answer I was looking for, but I haven't been on serverfault in the past two weeks, and the bounty period has expired. Also there seems no way I can reinstate the bounty and give you the points (I think I was offering 250 points?).Not only that, I can no longer mark this or any other submission as the answer. Andy, I am really sorry about this. Wish I had some way to make it right.

Comment: @quux - no worries, I appreciate the note. I'm just glad you got what you were looknig for.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that this:

gwmi -namespace "root\cimv2" -list

returns an array of ManagementClass .Net objects, so you can use ManagementClass.Properties collection to select properties that have a certain string in their names. Here is my PowerShell script:

```
foreach($class in gwmi -namespace "root\cimv2" -list)
{
    foreach($property in $class.Properties)
    {
        if($property.Name.Contains('Memory'))
        {
            $class.Name  + ' --- ' + $property.Name
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am a PowerShell beginner, but I think you can make a 'one-liner' from that.

Comment: This definitely returns what I was looking for. I'm very much a PS beginner as well, so I am noodling with it to see how I would create the one-liner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think by listing the namespace you get WMI CLASS Objects, but not the actual object instances - which you get by gwmi "win32_OperatingSystem"
If you use gm you will see:

TypeName: System.Management.**ManagementClass**#ROOT\cimv2\Win32_OperatingSystem
vs
TypeName: System.Management.**ManagementObject**#root\cimv2\Win32_OperatingSystem

edit:
You could do something like this:

`gwmi -namespace "root\cimv2" -list | %{ gwmi -class $_.name.tostring()}`

and if you want all properties with mem* then you could try 
`| select-object "mem*"`

but I'm not sure if that is really what you want. 
I think this is very ineffective if you just need to know the amount of memory. What do you really want to have as output?

Comment: OK, so how do I get object instance?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late here, but i'm pretty sure the below will get you to where you are looking to get - that is a listing of all the properties in the WMI namespace that have "mem" in thier name

```
foreach ($i in gwmi -namespace "root\cimv2" -list ){$i.properties | where-object {$_.name -match 'mem'}| format-table origin,name}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but I liked the output formatting and simplicity of Andy's answer better. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Download Microsoft's Scriptomatic2 and PowershellScriptomatic.  They're both hta apps, so you can view them as plain text to see how they do it.

Comment: Thank you, but no. I have used both, they are fine for enumerating properties of a single WMI object, but no good for more complex scenarios like this one.

Comment: My point is that the apps both apps demonstrate how to iterate over all of the CIM namespaces and all objects (and properties) within each.  Perhaps I wasn't clear; I didn't mean for you to run the apps, but rather open them in a text editor and browse the source.